# Ncurses menu - remembering selection

Tags: c, menu, ncurses

I am using Ncurses library to do some interactive menus, and I don't know how to do one thing. I have simple menu with few options, I turned of `O_ONEVALUE` so many options can be selected at the same time, before posting menu I get all the menu items and mark them as selected or not, depending on a bit mask that I keep stored somewhere else, but when the menu is posted every option is turned off, here is the code:

```
//acquiring menu items
ITEM** header_items = menu_items(params.header_opts_menu);
ITEM* cur_item;
if (header_items == NULL)
{
    client_cleanup();
    syslog_nsys_f(LOG_ERR, "error while getting header menu items");
}
//selecting appropriate items
long header_menu_items_count = ARRAY_SIZE(header_menu_choices);
for (i = 0; i < header_menu_items_count; ++i)
{
    if ((params.header_flags & (1 << (i))) != 0)
        decision = TRUE;
    else
        decision = FALSE;
    if (set_item_value(header_items[i], TRUE) != E_OK)
    {
        client_cleanup();
        syslog_nsys_f(LOG_ERR,"error while setting menu item value");
    }
}
if (post_menu(params.header_opts_menu) != E_OK)
{
    client_cleanup();
    syslog_nsys_f(LOG_ERR,"error while posting header options menu");
}
set_menu_items(params.header_opts_menu,header_items);
refresh();
```

even if I set value of every item to `TRUE` nothing happens, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to call set_menu_items after calling post_menu.  Check the return value from set_menu_items you are probably getting an E_POSTED error.